# Box coordinates numpy sum

Tags: python, numpy

I'm just wondering how to do a sum within a specific area of a 3D map and save it to a fits file. For example the xmin is 61, xmax is 107 and I have values for the ymin and ymax. The z coordinate is all 0. I want to sum everything within that box.

the lines I have right now are

```
coords = [(61,68,0) , (107,117,0)]
mySum = np.sum(coords, axis=0)
pf.writeto('sum1.fits', mySum)
```

but that obviously did not work as I'm just specifying two points on a 3D map and not an area so would I have to add them?

Comment: If you want to sum over all values of `coords`, just do `np.sum(coords)`, without specifying the `axis`.

Comment: Where is the "map" you want to sum over in your example?